# Integer cube root

Tags: c, optimization, math, gcc, numerical-analysis

I'm looking for fast code for 64-bit (unsigned) cube roots.  (I'm using C and compiling with gcc, but I imagine most of the work required will be language- and compiler-agnostic.)  I will denote by ulong a 64-bit unisgned integer.

Given an input n I require the (integral) return value r to be such that

```
r * r * r <= n && n < (r + 1) * (r + 1) * (r + 1)
```

That is, I want the cube root of n, rounded down.  Basic code like

```
return (ulong)pow(n, 1.0/3);
```

is incorrect because of rounding toward the end of the range.  Unsophisticated code like

```
ulong
cuberoot(ulong n)
{
    ulong ret = pow(n + 0.5, 1.0/3);
    if (n < 100000000000001ULL)
        return ret;
    if (n >= 18446724184312856125ULL)
        return 2642245ULL;
    if (ret * ret * ret > n) {
        ret--;
        while (ret * ret * ret > n)
            ret--;
        return ret;
    }
    while ((ret + 1) * (ret + 1) * (ret + 1) <= n)
        ret++;
    return ret;
}
```

gives the correct result, but is slower than it needs to be.

This code is for a math library and it will be called many times from various functions.  Speed is important, but you can't count on a warm cache (so suggestions like a 2,642,245-entry binary search are right out).

For comparison, here is code that *correctly* calculates the integer square root.

```
ulong squareroot(ulong a) {
    ulong x = (ulong)sqrt((double)a);
    if (x > 0xFFFFFFFF || x*x > a)
        x--;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: What is the slow part of your "Unsophisticated" implementation? is it the pow() call or one/both of the loops?

Comment: The pow call is expensive (~140 clocks by instruction counting).  The rest isn't free, though, especially with branch misprediction; it costs maybe 80 clocks factoring that in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The book "Hacker's Delight" has algorithms for this and many other problems. The code is online [here](http://www.hackersdelight.org/HDcode/icbrt.c.txt). *EDIT*: That code doesn't work properly with 64-bit ints, and the instructions in the book on how to fix it for 64-bit are somewhat confusing. A proper 64-bit implementation (including test case) is online [here](https://gist.github.com/729557).

I doubt that your `squareroot` function works "correctly" - it should be `ulong a` for the argument, not `n` :) (but the same approach would work using `cbrt` instead of `sqrt`, although not all C math libraries have cube root functions).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I can try that, but it's not clear to me that x (in the corresponding problem) will never be too small.  I'll look at the link, though.

Comment: The Hacker's Delight code certainly doesn't work for 64-bit integers; it fails for 8589934592, 8589934593, 8602523648, ....  I may be able to adapt it, though.

Comment: The squareroot() adaptation (sqrt -> cbrt, 0xFFFFFFFF -> 2642245) also fails, starting at 3375.  If a guard is put on both sides it fails at 18446724184312856125.

Comment: Oops, sorry. There's an overflow in the code if used as-is for 64-bit ints. The problem (and its fix) is described in the book, but it's apparently not in the code on the website. Fixed version here: https://gist.github.com/728432

Comment: That code doesn't seem to work for me -- it seems to return 0 in [almost] all cases.  Would you verify that it works for you?

Comment: Woops, yeah, there's a typo. The `(y * 1)` in the assignment to `b` should be `y + 1`, just as in the original code.

Comment: Still returns 0.  Should the decrement of s happen later?

Comment: Argh, sorry. Turns out the code in the book has bugs too :). Anyway, fixed version (tested this time, including test driver!) is here: https://gist.github.com/729557. The function is monotonic (it's effectively a binary search for digits of the cube root) and the test driver checks all "critical" points (0, i**3 and (i**3)-1 for all i so that the computation doesn't overflow, and 0xffffffffffffffff). At least when compiled with VC++, this one definitely does the right thing :)

Comment: [`cbrt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cbrt) has been available since C99 so it should exist for all modern compilers

Answer (score 5):

I've adapted the algorithm presented in `1.5.2` (the *kth* root) in [Modern Computer Arithmetic (Brent and Zimmerman)](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/%7Ebrent/pub/pub226.html). For the case of `(k == 3)`, and given a 'relatively' accurate over-estimate of the initial guess - this algorithm seems to out-perform the 'Hacker's Delight' code above.

Not only that, but [MCA](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/%7Ebrent/pd/mca-cup-0.5.9.pdf) as a text provides theoretical background as well as a proof of correctness and terminating criteria.

Provided that we can produce a 'relatively' good initial **over-estimate**, I haven't been able to find a case that exceeds (7) iterations. (Is this effectively related to 64-bit values having 2^6 bits?) Either way, it's an improvement over the (21) iterations in the HacDel code - with linear **O(b)** convergence, despite having a loop body that is evidently much faster.

The initial estimate I've used is based on a 'rounding up' of the number of significant bits in the value (**x**). Given (**b**) significant bits in (**x**), we can say: **`2^(b - 1) <= x < 2^b`**. I state without proof (though it should be relatively easy to demonstrate) that: **`2^ceil(b / 3) > x^(1/3)`**

---

```
static inline uint32_t u64_cbrt (uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t r0 = 1, r1;

    /* IEEE-754 cbrt *may* not be exact. */

    if (x == 0) /* cbrt(0) : */
        return (0);

    int b = (64) - __builtin_clzll(x);
    r0 <<= (b + 2) / 3; /* ceil(b / 3) */

    do /* quadratic convergence: */
    {
        r1 = r0;
        r0 = (2 * r1 + x / (r1 * r1)) / 3;
    }
    while (r0 < r1);

    return ((uint32_t) r1); /* floor(cbrt(x)); */
}
```

---

A `crbt` call probably isn't all that useful - unlike the `sqrt` call which can be efficiently implemented on modern hardware. That said, I've seen gains for sets of values under `2^53` (exactly represented in IEEE-754 doubles), which surprised me.

The only downside is the division by: **`(r * r)`** - this can be slow, as the latency of integer division continues to fall behind other advances in ALUs. The division by a constant: `(3)` is handled by reciprocal methods on any modern optimising compiler.

It's interesting that Intel's 'Icelake' microarchitecture will significantly improve integer division - an operation that seems to have been neglected for a long time. I simply won't trust the 'Hacker's Delight' answer until I can find a sound theoretical basis for it. And then I have to work out which variant is the 'correct' answer.

Comment: Could you clarify how you tested that "this algorithm seems to out-perform the 'Hacker's Delight' code above"? I tried a short test (< 1 sec) and a long test (~1 min) based on some code I had lying around and got vastly different results. It would be interesting to know under what conditions each implementation is faster.

Answer (score 4):

If `pow` is too expensive, you can use a count-leading-zeros instruction to get an approximation to the result, then use a lookup table, then some Newton steps to finish it.

```
int k = __builtin_clz(n); // counts # of leading zeros (often a single assembly insn)
int b = 64 - k;           // # of bits in n
int top8 = n >> (b - 8);  // top 8 bits of n (top bit is always 1)
int approx = table[b][top8 & 0x7f];
```

Given `b` and `top8`, you can use a lookup table (in my code, 8K entries) to find a good approximation to `cuberoot(n)`.  Use some Newton steps (see comingstorm's answer) to finish it.

Comment: Maybe you could try converting the ulong to a float, and index on the top 16 bits.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a Newton's step to fix your rounding errors:

```
ulong r = (ulong)pow(n, 1.0/3);
if(r==0) return r; /* avoid divide by 0 later on */
ulong r3 = r*r*r;
ulong slope = 3*r*r;

ulong r1 = r+1;
ulong r13 = r1*r1*r1;

/* making sure to handle unsigned arithmetic correctly */
if(n >= r13) r+= (n - r3)/slope;
if(n < r3)   r-= (r3 - n)/slope;
```

A single Newton step ought to be enough, but you may have off-by-one (or possibly more?) errors.  You can check/fix those using a final check&increment step, as in your OQ:

```
while(r*r*r > n) --r;
while((r+1)*(r+1)*(r+1) <= n) ++r;
```

or some such.

(I admit I'm lazy; the right way to do it is to carefully check to determine which (if any) of the check&increment things is actually necessary...)

Comment: Good idea, but I don't think that pow is ever off by more than two so Newton's method is overkill.

Comment: So, maybe some less-expensive approximation + Newton's method would be faster?

Comment: Maybe.  I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

```
// On my pc: Math.Sqrt 35 ns, cbrt64 <70ns, cbrt32 <25 ns, (cbrt12 < 10ns)

// cbrt64(ulong x) is a C# version of:
// http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/acbrt.c.txt     (acbrt1)

// cbrt32(uint x) is a C# version of:
// http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/icbrt.c.txt     (icbrt1)

// Union in C#:
// http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UnionsOrAnEquivalentInCSairamasTipOfTheDay.aspx

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]  
public struct fu_32   // float <==> uint
{
[FieldOffset(0)]
public float f;
[FieldOffset(0)]
public uint u;
}

private static uint cbrt64(ulong x)
{
    if (x >= 18446724184312856125) return 2642245;
    float fx = (float)x;
    fu_32 fu32 = new fu_32();
    fu32.f = fx;
    uint uy = fu32.u / 4;
    uy += uy / 4;
    uy += uy / 16;
    uy += uy / 256;
    uy += 0x2a5137a0;
    fu32.u = uy;
    float fy = fu32.f;
    fy = 0.33333333f * (fx / (fy * fy) + 2.0f * fy);
    int y0 = (int)                                      
        (0.33333333f * (fx / (fy * fy) + 2.0f * fy));    
    uint y1 = (uint)y0;                                 

    ulong y2, y3;
    if (y1 >= 2642245)
    {
        y1 = 2642245;
        y2 = 6981458640025;
        y3 = 18446724184312856125;
    }
    else
    {
        y2 = (ulong)y1 * y1;
        y3 = y2 * y1;
    }
    if (y3 > x)
    {
        y1 -= 1;
        y2 -= 2 * y1 + 1;
        y3 -= 3 * y2 + 3 * y1 + 1;
        while (y3 > x)
        {
            y1 -= 1;
            y2 -= 2 * y1 + 1;
            y3 -= 3 * y2 + 3 * y1 + 1;
        }
        return y1;
    }
    do
    {
        y3 += 3 * y2 + 3 * y1 + 1;
        y2 += 2 * y1 + 1;
        y1 += 1;
    }
    while (y3 <= x);
    return y1 - 1;
}

private static uint cbrt32(uint x)
{
    uint y = 0, z = 0, b = 0;
    int s = x < 1u << 24 ? x < 1u << 12 ? x < 1u << 06 ? x < 1u << 03 ? 00 : 03 :
                                                         x < 1u << 09 ? 06 : 09 :
                                          x < 1u << 18 ? x < 1u << 15 ? 12 : 15 :
                                                         x < 1u << 21 ? 18 : 21 :
                           x >= 1u << 30 ? 30 : x < 1u << 27 ? 24 : 27;
    do
    {
        y *= 2;
        z *= 4;
        b = 3 * y + 3 * z + 1 << s;
        if (x >= b)
        {
            x -= b;
            z += 2 * y + 1;
            y += 1;
        }
        s -= 3;
    }
    while (s >= 0);
    return y;
}

private static uint cbrt12(uint x) // x < ~255
{
    uint y = 0, a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;
    while (a < x)
    {
        y++;
        b += c;
        a += b;
        c += 6;
    }
    if (a != x) y--;
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the code within the GitHub gist from the answer of Fabian Giesen, I have arrived at the following, faster implementation:

```
static inline uint64_t icbrt(uint64_t x) {
  uint64_t b, y, one = 1, bits = 3*21;
  int s;
  for (s = bits - 3; s >= 0; s -= 3) {
    if ((x >> s) == 0)
      continue;
    x -= one << s;
    y = 1;
    for (s = s - 3; s >= 0; s -= 3) {
      y += y;
      b = 1 + 3*y*(y + 1);
      if ((x >> s) >= b) {
        x -= b << s;
        y += 1;
      }
    }
    return y;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

While the above is still somewhat slower than methods relying on the GNU specific `__builtin_clzll`, the above does not make use of compiler specifics and is thus completely portable.

#### The `bits` constant

Lowering the constant `bits` leads to faster computation, but the highest number `x` for which the function gives correct results is `(1 << bits) - 1`. Also, `bits` must be a multiple of `3` and be at most `64`, meaning that its maximum value is really `3*21 == 63`. With `bits = 3*21`, `icbrt()` thus works for input `x <= 9223372036854775807`. If we know that a program is working with limited `x`, say `x < 1000000`, then we can speed up the cube root computation by setting `bits = 3*7`, since `(1 << 3*7) - 1 = 2097151 >= 1000000`.

#### 64-bit vs. 32-bit integers

Though the above is written for 64-bit integers, the logic is the same for 32-bit:

```
#include <stdint.h>

static inline uint32_t icbrt(uint32_t x) {
  uint32_t b, y, bits = 3*7;  /* or whatever is appropriate */
  int s;
  for (s = bits - 3; s >= 0; s -= 3) {
    if ((x >> s) == 0)
      continue;
    x -= 1 << s;
    y = 1;
    for (s = s - 3; s >= 0; s -= 3) {
      y += y;
      b = 1 + 3*y*(y + 1);
      if ((x >> s) >= b) {
        x -= b << s;
        y += 1;
      }
    }
    return y;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your 64 bit icbrt() function doesn't work for all inputs. It says icbrt(12200509765705839) = 243582 when it should be 230210.

Comment: Indeed there was a subtle bug. Introducing the `one` variable above fixes it. Try again with the slightly edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would [research how to do it by hand](http://www.google.ca/search?q=cube+root+extraction+algorithm), and then translate that into a computer algorithm, working in base 2 rather than base 10.

We end up with an algorithm something like (pseudocode):

```
Find the largest n such that (1 << 3n) < input.
result = 1 << n.
For i in (n-1)..0:
    if ((result | 1 << i)**3) < input:
        result |= 1 << i.
```

We can optimize the calculation of `(result | 1 << i)**3` by observing that the bitwise-or is equivalent to addition, refactoring to `result**3 + 3 * i * result ** 2 + 3 * i ** 2 * result + i ** 3`, caching the values of `result**3` and `result**2` between iterations, and using shifts instead of multiplication.

Comment: Interesting.  As written, not quite competitive with the naive version, but should be close (enough to require testing; instruction counting suggests < 370 cycles). I don't think your replacement of (result | 1 << i)**3 is actually an optimization, though -- you're at least two multiplies and 6+ other instructions and need to update result^3 and result^2 each time the if is taken.  But with other optimizations this might work...?

Comment: @Charles updating result^3 and result^2 comes for free, because they need to be calculated in the current step anyway. I'll write it out and edit.

Comment: @Charles ... Never mind, it doesn't work the way I thought it would. :(

Comment: I think yours is a good idea, and it might combine well with comingstorm's idea (yours to some level, then take over with Newton). I don't mind that it doesn't quite work now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try and adapt this C algorithm :

```c
#include <limits.h>

// return a number that, when multiplied by itself twice, makes N. 
unsigned cube_root(unsigned n){
    unsigned a = 0, b;
    for (int c = sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT / 3 * 3 ; c >= 0; c -= 3) {
        a <<= 1;
        b = a + (a << 1), b = b * a + b + 1 ;
        if (n >> c >= b)
            n -= b << c, ++a;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Also there is :

```c
// return the number that was multiplied by itself to reach N.
unsigned square_root(const unsigned num) {
    unsigned a, b, c, d;
    for (b = a = num, c = 1; a >>= 1; ++c);
    for (c = 1 << (c & -2); c; c >>= 2) {
        d = a + c;
        a >>= 1;
        if (b >= d)
            b -= d, a += c;
    }
    return a;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/michel-leonard/C-MathSnip/blob/main/simple_functions.c)

Answer (score 0):

A ***VERY VERY*** lazy way to obtain an approximate starting point for # of bits that's a multiple of 3 ::

— *The `- 1` at the end is essential since the right-most digit (to the left of radix) is always the 0-th power of any base when expressed in big-endian notation*

---

> ```
> 3 * ( str_len(sprintf("%o", x)) - 1 )
> ```

---

```
 e.g.        x :=        65 812 642 870 067 
       
         octal ==> 8 # 1 675 546 314 631 463
 string length ==> 16
  approx. bits ==> 45
```

---

`45` is indeed correct, since this number is just slightly shy of `2 ^ 46`

Yes it's a very lazy way, but might not be all that fast, since it still has to process the full octal for you, even at reduced precision.

Although my own adaptation of the Hacker's Delight algo above to `awk` doesn't directly use this `sprintf()` approach, I do a rapid scan of

```
   x  <  8 ^ 8  <=  x            ( 16,777,216 | 1 << 24 )
```

---

- ```
  below it, just one more check for 

   x  <  8 ^ 4  <=  x               ( 4,096 | 1 << 12 )
  ```

---

```
at or above 8 ^ 8 check for
```

- ```
   x < 8 ^ 12 <=> x < 8 ^ 16 <= x ( 1 << 36 | 1 << 48 )
  ```

---

- ```
   within these 2, figure out which one is suitable for x,

   otherwise, just set it to the max of 60-bits, or 8^20
  ```

`8's` are very convenient in this regard since, by definition, any and every power of 8 is a power of 2 that's divisible by 3.

####################################

**UPDATE 1 ::** fully `POSIX`-compliant `awk` adaptation of algorithm above,

*1. looping by powers of 8 instead of 2 simplifies the tracking of
exponent :::
**`s -= 3`** `=>` **`--s`**

2. function returns a negative integer representing the
   real/non-complex cube root for negative inputs
3. the accepted range is wider than either unsigned 64-bit or
   signed 64-bit in the traditional sense
4. due to lack of native bit-shifting in `awk`, no division/modulo
   ops are used by the function
5. all coefficients, offsets, bases, and exponents required by the
   function are generated on the fly, eliminating the need to hard-code in "magic numbers"*

---

```
function cuberoot(__, ___, ____, _____, ________,
                   _, ______, _______, _________) {

    ## Sources :
    ##
    ## [-1-] "Hacker*s Delight"
    ## [-2-] stackoverflow.com/questions/4331820/
    ##                        integer-cube-root/76684580
    ##
    ##  __| input :: (sign agnostic) 64-bit integer, string or numeric
    ##    |           range (inclusive) : [ 1 - 16^16,
    ##    |                                     16^16 - 1 ]
    ##    |
    ##    |--> noncomplex("real") integer cube-root
    ##

    if (_ = (___ = +__) < (_<_) && __!= "")
        return \
            -cuberoot(-___)

    if (_ = (__ += ____ = _) <= (___ = (_ += ++_)^++_))
        return \
            (__ ? _ + (__ == ___) : +__)

       _____ = __ < (___ = (_ += _________ = ++_) * (_+=_))^___ \
                    ? _ + _ * (___^_ <= __) \
              : __ < ___^(_ * _) \
                    ? _ *(_ - (__ < ___^(_ + ___)) \
                                ) : _ + _ * _ + !!_
    ________ = ___
     _______ = --_ + (___ = !--_)

    do  __ < (______ = ________^_____ * (_______ * \
             ((____ *= _ + _) + (___ += ___)) + _________)) \
                                                       ? _ : \
                 __ -= ! (____ += ___ + ++___) + ______
    while(_____--)

    return ___
}
```

Comment: Cute method, thanks!